# How to bind to an owning window's control-property (from a dialog window)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My friends,

i Have a problem in WPF which i just cannot solve. I have two Windows, **Mainwindow** and **Window1**. I'd like to bind a ListView in my child-window to a controls property in the parent-window. In detail:

Mainwindow has a control declared in XAML,

`<local:MyControl x:Name="View"/>`

Further down i have a Listview which get's fed by a public property of 'View', 'Session.Events' (Observable Collection)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=Session.Events}"/>
```

Which works fine, but now i have a second Window spawned from Mainwindow in such manner:

```
Window1 MyWin1 = new Window1();
MyWin1.Owner = this;
MyWin1.ShowDialog();
```

And this second window has a ListView which also needs to be fed by my 'View' control. I'd like to do it via binding but i bite my teeth out. It does not work, whatever i try. I do have a working version via code-behind ...

```
Window1 Parent = (Window1)this.Owner;
MyListView.ItemsSource = Parent.CCView.Session.Events;
```

But i would prefer doing the bind in XAML and save the extra-code. Also i hope it will help me to understand bindings better, which for me are still a mystery to some extend.

Thank you so much and my best regards,
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind across the logical tree of your XAML. The second window is not part of the first window's tree. I'd think the most simple way in your situation should be to pass over the DataContext to your child window:

```
MyWin1 = new Window1 {
  DataContext = this.DataContext,
  Owner = this 
};
MyWin1.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Hi flq, thanks for the hint! I included it, but how do i exercise the actual binding in Window1? i tried ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=Session.Events}" and a bunch of other things but i can't get it to work ...

Comment: hm, looks like you are not using a DataContext? It would make sense, though, that way you know what your bindings refer to. If e.g. your DataContext is Session, the binding is `{Binding Events}` - The DataContext gets inherited all the way down the logical tree

Comment: One more question, why does: Win1.DataContext = this.View; ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Session.Events} work, but not: Win1.DataContext = this; ItemsSource="{Binding Path=View.Session.Events}" ?

Comment: Suppose if you set MyWin1.DataContext to this.CCView.Session.Events, your binding will look like this ItemsSource={Binding}.

Comment: it could be that "View" is generated as a private / internal member, hence it would not be seen from the outside

Comment: I tried to set the x:Fieldmodifier to public, still no luck. But it starts to make sense now, the XAML compiler declares fields (or so i figured), not properties - and WPF by standard cannot access fields. If i bind to a property, say Title, in a general DataContext provided by 'this' it works. Thanks again, i learned alot today. (-: